# How did I get a Caucus Badge?

Tags: support, badges

How did I get a [Caucus Badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/88/caucus?userid=3383) when I was not even very active on scifi.SE when the scifi election was taking place??

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your profile, I can see that you visited the site during the election period (2012-01-23 20:00Z to 2012-02-07 20:00Z), even though you took no recorded activity (posts, comments, etc.) during that time. I can't tell what pages you visited, presumably you did visit the [election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election).

The badge is new, it was granted retroactively when it was created last week.

Comment: This is all on presumption. Which is odd.

Comment: @TheDoctor Only the developers have the logs, and that's what they used to determine who got the badge.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is visit the site once during that time, that it recorded your visit. Perhaps the system is a bit buggy as well... Were you active on any SE sites at that time?

Comment: I am quite active on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My guess is, you visited the site in the 3 week period of time that elections were occuring, and recieved the badge then. Only a quick visit would be required.